# JEditorPane with nested div overflowing with a scrollbar

Tags: java, scrollbar, overflow, jeditorpane

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a `JEditorPane` that is able to display / render (i.e. not editable) HTML content that has a nested `div` of fixed size or width, and that contains bigger inner content.

In particular I'm interested in wider content, that the the JEditorPane has width.
I.e. I would like this nested `div` to *overflow* on the X axis and as such show an horizontal scrollbar on this `div` only. The rest of the sibling content nodes of that div can be word wrapped.

[image: example]

From the HTML point of view the `div`, container should have the style `overflow-x: auto;`. In the above example the content is text, but really I'm looking at anything that is wider, e.g. a table, an image, etc.

Given Swing supports only HTML 3.2, I don't think this might be quite possible. But I may be wrong as I don't quite get yet if `ViewFactory` / `View` could be helpful there to somewhat install a `JScrollPane`.

Just in case, I don't want to put the whole `JEditorPane` in a `JScrollPane`.

Comment: You want the html to be rendered in a component as a web browser would do it?

Comment: Only for the nested element "overflow", i.e like if the JEditorPane had a nested `JScrollPane`. I'm not looking for a full support of web browser.